# If a speakers specification says it is a 30 Watt speaker, why can’t the formula for decibels be used to convert the 30 watts to dB?

Tags: levels

In the following example, I try to determine how many watts would be required to create a 64.5RMB source output.  But the result is too small, even though the equation appears correct.

[image: input]

[image: output]

Comment: This looks full nonsense. Here in far west sound pressure levels are measured as decibels over the hearing treshold. Acoustic radiation power can be told as watts, but that's not common, because in practical applications the sound pressure level as a function of place is the interesting result.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one more specification needed: effiency also known as sensitivity. Converting electricity to sound is very ineffecient.

Typical values of sensitivy is around 90dB sound level for 1 W of elecrical power. Using that you can translate your 30W maximum input into sound level.

Example: 90db/W, 30 W --> 105dB  (90 + 14,77)

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what “RMB” is supposed to be and what your numbers are supposed to signify, but the log in dB is a log in base 10.  That would leave you with x=0.000135 for whatever you are trying to solve here.

Another thing worth noting is that a 30 W speaker does not produce a maximum of 30 W of acoustic power, but consumes a maximum of 30 W of electric power.  Speakers are marvelously inefficient, with acoustical energy in 1 m distance for 1W of input varying between something like 85 dB for compact HiFi equipment to 115 dB for high-efficiency horn-loaded compression drivers intended for PA.  And “high-efficiency” still is just dipping in the double-digit percentages.

Answer (score 0):

What you're calculating is the electrical power required to generate a 64.5 dB **Sound Power Level** (SWL) from a 100% efficient speaker.

SWL measures the total power radiated from a source, not how much of it reaches our ears (or measurement device) at a particular location. What we generally use when discussing level of sounds in our environment is the **Sound Pressure Level** (SPL).  SPL is *related to* SWL, but depends on distance from the source, as well as the characteristics surrounding environment.

ghellquist's answer is correct, but incomplete. The speaker sensitivity is measured for 1 W of electrical power **at 1 m distance**, so as soon as you move your ears (or measuring device) more than 1 meter from the source, that SPL will decrease. In an ideal environment with sound radiating out in a sphere, the SPL will reduce by 6 dB for every doubling of distance.